# know the last screen installed

Tags: c#, screen

I need to know the last screen installed on a pc. I used this:

```
int nScreen = Screen.AllScreens.Length
```

I have 4 monitors, ordered as 1-3-2-4 but nScreen returns me the third (n.2), not the last (n.4).

Comment: What is Screen?

Comment: System.Windows.Forms.Screen

Answer (score 0):

Try this way:

```
System.Windows.Forms.Screen screen = System.Windows.Forms.Screen.AllScreens.Last();
```

Comment: Thanks but it does not work; in my monitor order: 1-3-2-4, returns no. 2 and not the n. 4.